# Does WindsorContainer.Resolve<T>() always return the same instance?

Tags: castle-windsor

I was under the impression that using the Resolve method returned a new instance of the type you want to resolve? Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the component's `LifeStyleType` is configured as `Singleton`, it will resolve to the same instance.

Comment: ARRRG!!! I remember reading that now. I've been troubleshooting for the last hour.